# How can a bicycle wheel built with concurrent spokes be solid?

Tags: kinematics, angular-momentum, torque

Consider the fixed point at the top of Figure A. That point is connected by a strong but thin metal rod—one acting like a rope—to the hinged point at the bottom of the figure.

When we apply a horizontal force to the left, the metal rod is able to handle only the component of the force linear with it. The rod is so thin that it cannot handle bending, and can hence carry no bending moments.

[image: component of force linear with a thin rod]

This is essentially how spokes function on a bicycle wheel. They are arranged and tension is inserted into them at the nipples (joints at the rims). The rim carries the resulting constant compression force.

I had always imagined that the traditional method of arranging the spokes (left of the figure below) is a result of the discussion over Figure A above. The spokes connect at the hub. When a torque is applied at the hubs, whether from the drivetrain on a rear wheel, or from disc brakes at the hubs of either front or rear brakes, the torque becomes a collection of additional tension forces in some spokes, and a reduction of the existing tension in other spokes. (The spokes would buckle if they were ever subjected to compression forces; they are simply too thin for their length.)

[image: concurrent spokes in a built wheel]

But increasingly over the past many years, I see bicycle wheels on the market whose spokes are arranged such that they are not tangents or near tangents at the hubs. The spokes are concurrent at the center of the wheel.

I have difficulty accepting that a wheel constructed in such a way can be rigid. I feel that the hub **must** rotate with respect to the rim by a small, but not insignificant angle, until the spokes can carry the tension by the component of the forces linear with each spoke. In Figure B above, the rod only weakly resists the motion of the hinged point at the bottom. That point must **first** appreciably move before the rod (spoke) can resist further movement. But such an appreciable move would mean that the wheel behaves as a mushy, nonrigid object. A bicycle wheel **is** of course a nonrigid object. That's how it can be built to be so light yet so strong to carry a human over road bumps, but the resistance forces (additional tensions) arise from the rigid-object position of the hubs with respect to the rim, not from an initial movement that triggers those forces.

How can a bicycle wheel built with concurrent spokes be solid?

We ignore in this question:

1. Rim brakes
2. The asymmetric forces on a bike's wheel when it turns on flat terrain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your assessment is entirely correct.  My assumption is that such wheels do not support any significant torques.  Possibly you should ask this on the bicycling SE instead.

Your image above shows a pair of wheels.  My understanding is the radial spokes are only on the front wheel because the drive torque from the rear wheel cannot be supported.  It is just a weight optimization in situations where torques are not present.

You mention rim brakes are ignored.  The real question would be if disk brakes are ever present on such a radial spoke wheel.  I assume it is not because the torque would be too great.

Comment: Yep, disc brakes are never used with radial spokes.